# How secure is htaccess deny from all

Tags: php, security, .htaccess

I have a file that I don't want to be accessed by anyone except my own server (by php request). I am using the following in my .htaccess:

```
<Files myfile.xml>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</Files>
```

But was wondering, how secure is this? Is there anyway that someone might be able to get around this and get to the file directly?
In my php file I have:

```
simplexml_load_file("myfile.xml")
```

To get the data and also am using

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
```

So no one can access that file directly (only by Ajax)
What do you guys think about using this method?

Comment: If you really want to secure the file, place it outside document root... a directory 'not known' by apache.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to deny access to .ini file in .htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216019/is-it-safe-to-deny-access-to-ini-file-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're directly naming a file, it's only secure if `myfile.xml` is the ONLY way to get at that file. If someone has shell level access to your server, and can create a hardlink to that file using a different name, e.g. `ln myfile.xml heehee.txt`, then they'll be able to get the file's contents vi `heehee.txt`, because they're not getting at it via the 'myfile.xml'.

Best practice is to keep files outside of the document root entirely. This doesn't stop the symlink/hardlink attacks, but it does keep certain bypass attacks at bay.

Comment: But how would i access it via the php file if it is outside the root?

Comment: php is not bound by URL restrictions, because PHP operates at the file system level. you can include/fopen/file_get_contents a file ANYWHERE in the filesystem, even if Apache's got it locked down. PHP operates below Apache's security system.

Comment: That last comment is not necessarily true, and almost guaranteed to be wrong on shared servers. PHP has a base_restriction setting that can limit where you can access files from, and is usually enforced on shared hosting. The answer's right, but that last comment might be misleading in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you're reading the file in a script, this doesn't go through Apache at all, so you don't even to allow localhost. Simply deny all, and that's it.

(plus other answer about the best place is out of document root - only use deny all if your permissions don't let you put the file elsewhere, e.g. you have a base restriction in effect)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway that someone might be able to get around this and get
>   to the file directly?

In short, NO.

Is it secure.

That's why **Deny from all** was invented.

> What do you guys think about using this method?

Absolutely not necessary until you host foreign php code on your localhost.

Comment: think outside the box!: this is security on the webserver level only.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically security on webserver level. If there is another breach i.e. through an SQLI Attack which is using the local filesystem or some Remote File inclusion security breach you're pretty much pwned. So i would consider encrypting the file, and acl/chmod it down to the very most necessariest users/groups, and also most servers/webhosting companies provides a private/ dir for such data.